# Change variable in a column with a for loop using R

Tags: r

In my data frame, I have a column named `Localisation`. I want to change the data that is stored in it.

Thalamus, External capsule or Lenticulate for 0,
Cerebellum or Brain stem for 2 and
Frontal, Occipital, Parietal or Temporal for 1

I’m trying to do a For loop for this operation. My for statement doesn’t seem to be right, because I received

```
Error in for (. in i) 15:nrow(Localisation) : 
  4 arguments passed to 'for' which requires 3
```

and I don’t know how to compose my if statement.

```
dfM <- dfM %>%
  for(i in dfM$Localisation) if(i = "Thalamus"| "External capsule"| "Lenticulate"){
    dfM$Localisation <- "0"
  } else if ( i = "Cerebellum"| "Brain stem") {
    dfM$Localisation <- "2"
  } else {
    dfM$Localisation <- "1"
  }
```

I know similar questions have been asked multiple times, but I can’t find a way to work with my data.

```
dput(head(dfM))
structure(list(new_id = c("5", "9", "10", "16", "30", "31"), 
    Localisation = c("Frontal", "Thalamus", "Occipital ", "Frontal", 
    "External capsule", "Cerebellum"), HIV.CT.initial = c(0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Anticoagulant = c("Warfarin", "DOAC", 
    "Warfarin", "Warfarin", "Warfarin", "Warfarin"), Sex = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), HTA = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Systolic_BP = c(116L, 
    169L, 164L, 109L, 134L, 146L), Diastolic_BP = c(70L, 65L, 
    80L, 60L, 75L, 85L), ACO = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Type.NACO = c(NA, 
    2L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Dose.ACO = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    APT = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), INR = c(4.2, 1.1, 1.9, 1.3, 
    3.6, 2.8), GLW = c(13L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L), GLW.Prog = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 14L, NA), mRS = c(4L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L), Time.to.scan = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Chx = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Type.Chx = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Date.Chx = c("", 
    "", "", "", "", ""), décès.hospit = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L), décès.HIP = c(NA, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, NA), X3.mois = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), X6.mois = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), X12.mois = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), X3.mois.1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L), X6.mois.1 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L), X12.mois.1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), X.1.y = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ID = c(5L, 9L, 10L, 
    16L, 30L, 31L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing more of your code, but your syntax looks wrong.  For example, you need something like `for(i in 15:nrow(localisation)){ contents of loop }`, and `if(i == "Cerebellum"| i== "Brain stem")` or `if(i %in% c("Cerebellum", "Brain stem"))`.  And you don't need a `for` loop to do this - `ifelse` is a vectorised function.

Comment: Provide some of your data with `dput`. So, you would use `dput(head(dfM))`, then edit your question and paste the dput results.

Comment: It would be better to provide just the necessary column(s) and more rows, but this will do what you want: `tmp <- ifelse(dfM$Localisation %in% c("Thalamus", "External capsule", "Lenticulate"), "0", ifelse(dfM$Localisation %in% c("Cerebellum", "Brain stem"), "2", "1"))` and then `dfM$Localization <- tmp`. The `tmp` assignment keeps you from overwriting your original data until you are sure you have it working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up front: in general, don't use `for` in a `%>%`-pipe, it almost never is what you intend.

Since you have the `%>%`, I'll infer you're using `dplyr` and/or other related packages. Here's one way:

```r
library(dplyr)
dfM %>%
  mutate(Localisation = case_when(
    Localisation %in% c("Thalamus", "External capsule", "Lenticulate") ~ "0", 
    Localisation %in% c("Cerebellum", "Brain stem") ~ "2", 
    TRUE ~ "1")
  )
#   new_id Localisation HIV.CT.initial Anticoagulant Sex HTA Systolic_BP Diastolic_BP ACO Type.NACO Dose.ACO APT INR GLW GLW.Prog mRS Time.to.scan Chx Type.Chx Date.Chx décès.hospit décès.HIP X3.mois X6.mois X12.mois X3.mois.1 X6.mois.1 X12.mois.1 X.1.y ID
# 1      5            1              0      Warfarin   1   1         116           70   1        NA       NA   0 4.2  13       NA   4           NA   0       NA                     0        NA      NA      NA       NA        NA        NA         NA    NA  5
# 2      9            0              1          DOAC   1   1         169           65   0         2       NA   0 1.1  15       NA   3           NA   0       NA                     0        NA      NA      NA       NA        NA        NA         NA    NA  9
# 3     10            1              1      Warfarin   1   1         164           80   1        NA       NA   1 1.9  14       NA   4           NA   0       NA                     0        NA      NA      NA       NA        NA        NA         NA    NA 10
# 4     16            1              1      Warfarin   2   1         109           60   1        NA       NA   0 1.3  14       NA   6           NA   0       NA                     1         2      NA      NA       NA         1         1          1    NA 16
# 5     30            0              0      Warfarin   2   1         134           75   1        NA       NA   1 3.6  15       14   6           NA   0       NA                     1         1      NA      NA       NA         1         1          1    NA 30
# 6     31            2              0      Warfarin   1   0         146           85   1        NA       NA   0 2.8  15       NA   5           NA   0       NA                     0        NA       1      NA       NA         1         1          1    NA 31
```

Perhaps relevant: one of your values `"Occipital "` has a space at the end; if you have inadvertent spaces at times and need it to work, you can replace all references of `Localisation ==` to `trimws(Localisation) ==` to reduce the chance of a mis-classification.

Another method is to maintain a frame of translations:

```r
translations <- tribble(
  ~Localisation, ~NewLocalisation
  ,"Thalamus", "0", 
  ,"External capsule", "0", 
  ,"Lenticulate", "0", 
  ,"Cerebellum", "2", 
  ,"Brain stem", "2"
)

dfM %>%
  select(new_id, Localisation) %>%    # just to reduce the display here on SO
  left_join(., translations, by = "Localisation")
#   new_id     Localisation NewLocalisation
# 1      5          Frontal            <NA>
# 2      9         Thalamus               0
# 3     10       Occipital             <NA>
# 4     16          Frontal            <NA>
# 5     30 External capsule               0
# 6     31       Cerebellum               2
```

I intentionally left the "default" step out to highlight that the `NA` values are natural: those are the ones not specifically identified.

```r
dfM %>%
  left_join(., translations, by = "Localisation") %>%
  mutate(NewLocalisation = if_else(is.na(NewLocalisation), "1", NewLocalisation)) %>%
  mutate(Localisation = NewLocalisation) %>%
  select(-NewLocalisation)
#   new_id Localisation HIV.CT.initial Anticoagulant Sex HTA Systolic_BP Diastolic_BP ACO Type.NACO Dose.ACO APT INR GLW GLW.Prog mRS Time.to.scan Chx Type.Chx Date.Chx décès.hospit décès.HIP X3.mois X6.mois X12.mois X3.mois.1 X6.mois.1 X12.mois.1 X.1.y ID
# 1      5            1              0      Warfarin   1   1         116           70   1        NA       NA   0 4.2  13       NA   4           NA   0       NA                     0        NA      NA      NA       NA        NA        NA         NA    NA  5
# 2      9            0              1          DOAC   1   1         169           65   0         2       NA   0 1.1  15       NA   3           NA   0       NA                     0        NA      NA      NA       NA        NA        NA         NA    NA  9
# 3     10            1              1      Warfarin   1   1         164           80   1        NA       NA   1 1.9  14       NA   4           NA   0       NA                     0        NA      NA      NA       NA        NA        NA         NA    NA 10
# 4     16            1              1      Warfarin   2   1         109           60   1        NA       NA   0 1.3  14       NA   6           NA   0       NA                     1         2      NA      NA       NA         1         1          1    NA 16
# 5     30            0              0      Warfarin   2   1         134           75   1        NA       NA   1 3.6  15       14   6           NA   0       NA                     1         1      NA      NA       NA         1         1          1    NA 30
# 6     31            2              0      Warfarin   1   0         146           85   1        NA       NA   0 2.8  15       NA   5           NA   0       NA                     0        NA       1      NA       NA         1         1          1    NA 31
```

The reason I offer this alternative is that sometimes it's easier to maintain a separate table (in excel, CSV form, etc) in this fashion for automated processing of data. It doesn't offer any capability that the `case_when` or @dcarlson's `ifelse` methods do not.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your tips! It’s helping me to improve, as you might  have noticed I’m really a beginner.